# How to monitor headphoneAudioExposureEvent using Apple HealthKit?

Tags: swift, xcode, healthkit

I'm building an app which generates sounds and needs to monitor their volume.
I'm trying to use HealthKit for it and this is what I have done so far:

```
private let healthStore = HKHealthStore()

func observeHeadphoneAudio() {
    guard let type = HKObjectType.categoryType(forIdentifier: .headphoneAudioExposureEvent) else {
        return
    }
    healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: nil, read: [type]) { [weak self] success, error in
        if let error = error {
            log.warning(error.localizedDescription)
        } else if success {
            self?.fetch(type: type)
        }
    }
}

func fetch(type: HKCategoryType) {
    let descriptor = HKQueryDescriptor(sampleType: type, predicate: nil)
    let query = HKObserverQuery(queryDescriptors: [descriptor]) { query, samples, completion, error in
        if let error = error {
            log.warning(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        if let samples = samples {
            log.info(samples)
        }
    }
    healthStore.execute(query)
}
```

I'm starting it while generating a sound, query completion is executed once with empty samples set, and that's it.

What is the proper way to monitor headphone audio exposure?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for headphone audio exposure or headphone audio exposure event? The latter is generated when you exceed headphone audio exposure limits. See

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkquantitytypeidentifier/3081272-headphoneaudioexposure/
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkcategorytypeidentifier/3552059-headphoneaudioexposureevent

Comment: You are right. Thank you.